# Help me rewrite this code of getting Inline Help Text

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

This might become longer in the long run and I want to write this a cleaner way.

```
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getAuthProviderNameHelpText() {
        return Custom_App__mdt.Field_Name__c.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getAuthEndPointHelpText() {
        return Custom_App__mdt.Field_Endpoint_URL__c.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getConsumerKeyHelpText() {
        return Custom_App__mdt.Field_Key__c.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getConsumerSecretHelpText() {
        return Custom_App__mdt.Field_Secret__c.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getDefaultScopesHelpText() {
        return Custom_App__mdt.Field_Scope__c.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
    }
```

Would be cleaner if I could just call one method and pass a field name and return the
inlineHelptText.

```
   #######################
    pseudocode: 
        getFieldsHelpText(fieldName) {
           return fieldName.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
        }
   ########################
```

Comment: Have you looked at using [`fields.getmap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm#apex_describe_object_all_fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a less convoluted way, but I just tried 47 different ways in an Anonymous Apex window.

I kept getting the *Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context* and the *incorrect method signature* errors, so I just kept hacking away.

I cannot recall every thing that I tried, but the following works:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getFieldsHelpText(String fieldName) {
    return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Custom_App__mdt').getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
}
```

---

You could even "genericize" it more by doing the following:

```
public static String getFieldsHelpText(String objectName, String fieldName) {
    return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
}
```

Comment: I keep getting errors in my debug window. 
`System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`

Comment: Well, if you copied/pasted my code then you got the typo that I just discovered in my answer!  I put `Custom_App_mdt` when it should be `Custom_App__mdt`. (I used a Custom Metadata Type we have in our org, and so changed the name when I posted the answer.) I've edited my answer to correct the typo.